# MediaBrowserServiceCompat starts playing on its own

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat

Well, subj. Users report that on some devices (Doogee, Meizu) MediaBrowserServiceCompat starts playing after it's got paused and phone remains untouched for some time with it's screen off.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with OnAudioFocusChangeListener, not with MediaBrowserServiceCompat.

For some reason on these particular devices application was loosing and regaining audio focus while in the background, and I was starting playback once focus is aquired yet again.